# Only one ComponentDidMount per class component?

Tags: reactjs

This is an easy question I know but I can't find the answer to this for the life of me.

Can you only have on ComponentDidMount method per class component in React? Is it bad to have multiple? Will it work?

Comment: why do you need multiple `componentDidMount` in a single class component ? I don't think it is necessary to have multiple `componentDidMount` life cycle methods in your component because it only executes once during initial rendering !

Comment: I guess you are right, but I'm just thinking about separating different operations.

Comment: I'm not sure about `componentDidMount`, but surely you can use multiple `useEffect` with  functional components. In that case you can have it based on the operation you need to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple `componentDidMount` it will only run the last one (the others get overridden by the last declaration). See also: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-feather-gc6nr?file=/src/App.js.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can only have one componentDidMouny per class. But you could use an useEffect without adding dependencies. This behaves the same as a componentDidMount.